# Hide list items except the one you click on in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a HTML list as a React component where all list items are created from some data I loop through.

This is what I would like to achieve in React.

1. Click on one of the list items
2. Hide all other list items except the one I clicked on
3. Click on the list item that is showing
4. All list items should now show

Any ideas?

Thanks

Ian

Comment: Hi Ian! It seems that you're new to StackOverflow. Please have a read over [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Doing so will give other users a better chance of giving the answer you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<div id="app"></app>
```

And then :

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      one: "",
      two: "",
      three: "",
      four: "",
      clicked: false
    }
  }

  handleClick(name, event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.clicked){
      this.setState({one: "",two: "", three: "", four: "", clicked: false})
    }else{
      switch(name){
        case "One":
          this.setState({two: "hide", three: "hide", four: "hide", clicked: true});
          break;
          case "Two":
          this.setState({one: "hide", three: "hide", four: "hide", clicked: true});
          break;
          case "Three":
          this.setState({two: "hide", one: "hide", four: "hide", clicked: true});
          break;
          default:
          this.setState({two: "hide", three: "hide", one: "hide", clicked: true});
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <ul>
        <a href="" className={this.state.one} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "One")}><li >One</li></a>
        <a href="" className={this.state.two} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "Two")}><li>Two</li></a>
        <a href="" className={this.state.three} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "Three")}><li>Three</li></a>
        <a href="" className={this.state.four} onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, "Four")}><li>Four</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>;
  }
}


React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```